# Line up columns of numbers (print output in table format)

Tags: python

I have data (numbers) saved in the following format (example):

```
234 127 34 23 45567  
23 12 4 4 45  
23456 2 1 444 567  
...
```

Is there any python-way method to line up the numbers and get them as

```
  234  127  34   23  45567  
   23   12   4    4     45  
23456    2   1  444    567
```

(I cannot predict the column size).

Comment: look at the `.rjust(n)` method - left padding characters perhaps?

Comment: Is it unfeasible to iterate once through the data to determine maximum column size?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: pretty-printing ascii tables?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5909873/python-pretty-printing-ascii-tables)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [_How do I print parameters of multiple Python objects in table form?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12503655/how-do-i-print-parameters-of-multiple-python-objects-in-table-form)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Printing Lists as Tabular Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535954/printing-lists-as-tabular-data)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a simple, self-contained example that shows how to format variable column widths:

```
data = '''\
234 127 34 23 45567
23 12 4 4 45
23456 2 1 444 567'''

# Split input data by row and then on spaces
rows = [ line.strip().split(' ') for line in data.split('\n') ]

# Reorganize data by columns
cols = zip(*rows)

# Compute column widths by taking maximum length of values per column
col_widths = [ max(len(value) for value in col) for col in cols ]

# Create a suitable format string
format = ' '.join(['%%%ds' % width for width in col_widths ])

# Print each row using the computed format
for row in rows:
  print format % tuple(row)
```

which outputs:

> ```
>   234 127 34  23 45567
>    23  12  4   4    45
> 23456   2  1 444   567
> ```

Comment: Thanks for this. FWIW I made the columns left-justified by generating the format string with `'%%-%ds'`

Comment: Here's the relevant part with the new-style formats, left-aligned:
fmt = ' '.join(['{{:<{}}}'.format(width) for width in col_widths])
for row in rows:
  print fmt.format(*row)

Answer (score 10):

You need some way of finding the column size,
maybe by reading all the data and finding the maximum width.

```
>>> line='234 127 34 23 45567'
>>> line.split()
['234', '127', '34', '23', '45567']
>>> max(map(len, line.split()))
5
```

Repeat over all lines, to find column size (e.g., 5).
Constructing a formatted line with [`percent formatting`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) is straightforward.

```
>>> colsize = 5
>>> ' '.join(('%*s' % (colsize, i) for i in line.split()))
'  234   127    34    23 45567'
>>>
```

Comment: Didn't know about '%*s'.  Good tip!

Comment: The problem is that these numbers goes online and I don't know number of rows. To make it more readable I'd like to line them up. Thats it.

Comment: If you cannot compute the maximum width, just use a good guess, e.g. 10.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class ALIGN:
    LEFT, RIGHT = '-', ''

class Column(list):
    def __init__(self, name, data, align=ALIGN.RIGHT):
        list.__init__(self, data)
        self.name = name
        width = max(len(str(x)) for x in data + [name])
        self.format = ' %%%s%ds ' % (align, width)

class Table:
    def __init__(self, *columns):
        self.columns = columns
        self.length = max(len(x) for x in columns)
    def get_row(self, i=None):
        for x in self.columns:
            if i is None:
                yield x.format % x.name
            else:
                yield x.format % x[i]
    def get_rows(self):
        yield ' '.join(self.get_row(None))
        for i in range(0, self.length):
            yield ' '.join(self.get_row(i))

    def __str__(self):
        return '\n'.join(self.get_rows())
```

For your example:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print Table(
        Column("", [234, 32, 23456]),
        Column("", [127, 12, 2]),
        Column("", [34, 4, 1]),
        Column("", [23, 4, 444]),
        Column("", [45567, 45, 567])
    )
```

It will yield:

```
   234   127   34    23   45567 
    32    12    4     4      45 
 23456     2    1   444     567
```

Adapted from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577202-render-tables-for-text-interface/

Comment: That is incredibly heavyweight in view of some other solutions. What's the benefit of cooking up classes to handle this?

Comment: But this is so much more readable and elegant, dont you think?

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> rows = """234 127 34 23 45567
... 23 12 4 4 45
... 23456 2 1 444 567"""
```

first convert the rows into a 2d array (list of lists)

```
>>> arr=[x.split() for x in rows.split("\n")]
```

now compute the space each field will need to fit into

```
>>> widths = [max(map(len,(f[i] for f in tab))) for i in range(len(arr[0]))]
```

and pad each element to fit into that space

```
>>> [[k.rjust(widths[i]) for i,k in enumerate(j)] for j in arr]
[['  234', '127', '34', ' 23', '45567'], ['   23', ' 12', ' 4', '  4', '   45'], ['23456', '  2', ' 1', '444', '  567']]
```

finally join the array back into a string

```
>>> print "\n".join("  ".join(k.rjust(widths[i]) for i,k in enumerate(j)) for j in arr)
  234  127  34   23  45567
   23   12   4    4     45
23456    2   1  444    567
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this nice well documented example http://code.activestate.com/recipes/267662-table-indentation/

Answer (score 1):

Integer in front of the d is what column the integers will start after the previous
number so you can line them up however you see fit

`print("{0:4d} {1:4d} {2:4d} {3:4d} {4:4d}".format(234, 127, 34, 23, 45567))`

repeat as necessary

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Jacobs's answer modified to allow [a variable number of integers on each row](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/410687-transposing-a-list-of-lists-with-different-lengths/):

```
def align(data, delimiter = '\t', is_left_align = True):
  rows = [row.strip().split(delimiter) for row in data.split('\n')]
  cols = map(lambda *row: [str(field) or '' for field in row], *rows)
  widths = [max(len(field) for field in col) for col in cols]
  format = ['%%%s%ds' % ('-' if is_left_align else '', width) for width in widths]
  return '\n'.join([delimiter.join(format[:len(row)]) % tuple(row) for row in rows])

data = '''\
234 127 34 23 45567
23 12 4 4 45
23456 2 1 444 567'''
print(align(data, ' ', False))
```