# How do I print parameters of multiple objects in table form?

Tags: python, layout

I have a list of objects and I want to print the parameters of each in a nice table.

My code is here:

```
class item(object):
    def __init__(self, thing, owner, color):
        self.thing = thing
        self.owner = owner
        self.color = color

bin = []
bin.append(item('shirt', 'John', 'red'))
bin.append(item('skirt', 'Jane', 'blue'))    

## Need help here
## Can't figure this out

print '%-10s %-10s %-10s' % (bin[0].thing, bin[0].owner, bin[0].color)
```

The output I am trying to get is

```
shirt       skirt
John        Jane
red         blue
```

Comment: The usual convention is to capitalise the class name, so `Item` rather than `item`

Comment: FWIW, most of the "usual conventions" are detailed in [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for attr in ('thing', 'owner', 'color'):
    for item in bin:
        print '%-10s'%getattr(item, attr),
    print
```

It's more compact to use a list comprehension

```
for atts in ('thing', 'owner', 'color'):
    print ' '.join('%-10s'%getattr(item, attr) for item in bin)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's something I found long ago that's been very useful and still works. I finally got around recently to bringing it up to date with most of the latest Py 2.7.x and 3.x standards, although most of the changes were what I would call cosmetic and/or fairly trivial.

```
# File:    textformatter.py
# Author:  Hamish B Lawson
# Date:    19 Nov 1999
# from http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/4517
# Viewable via Internet Archive WayBackMachine:
# https://web.archive.org/web/20080709071216/http://www.faqts.com/knowledge_base/view.phtml/aid/4517
"""
Here is TextFormatter, a simple module for formatting text into
columns of specified widths. It does multiline wrapping and supports
LEFT, CENTER (or CENTRE), and RIGHT alignment.

Revisions:
    SKWM    Made filling & padding optional, tweaked some edge cases.
    MRM     Removed import of deprecated string module, made all classes
            explicitly new style, capitalized public constants, updated
            documentation. Tweaked test() function.
    MRM     Modified to work in both Python 2.7 and 3.x.
"""
from __future__ import print_function

LEFT, CENTER, RIGHT = range(3)
CENTRE = CENTER

class TextFormatter(object):
    """
    Formats text into columns.

    Constructor takes a list of dictionaries that each specify the
    properties for a column. Dictionary entries can be:

       'width'     : the width within which the text will be wrapped
       'alignment' : LEFT | CENTER | RIGHT
       'margin'    : number of space characters to prefix in front of column

    The compose() method takes a list of strings and returns a formatted
    string consisting of each string wrapped within its respective column.

    Example:
        import textformatter

        formatter = textformatter.TextFormatter(
            (
                {'width': 10},
                {'width': 12, 'margin': 4},
                {'width': 20, 'margin': 8, 'alignment': textformatter.RIGHT},
            )
        )

        print(formatter.compose(
            (
                "A rather short paragraph",
                "Here is a paragraph containing a veryveryverylongwordindeed.",
                "And now for something on the right-hand side.",
            )
        ))

    gives:

        A rather      Here is a                    And now for
        short         paragraph               something on the
        paragraph     containing a            right-hand side.
                      veryveryvery
                      longwordinde
                      ed.

    """
    class Column(object):

        def __init__(self, width=75, alignment=LEFT, margin=0, fill=1, pad=1):
            self.width = width
            self.alignment = alignment
            self.margin = margin
            self.fill = fill
            self.pad = pad
            self.lines = []

        def align(self, line):
            if self.alignment == CENTER:
                return line.center(self.width)
            elif self.alignment == RIGHT:
                return line.rjust(self.width)
            else:
                if self.pad:
                    return line.ljust(self.width)
                else:
                    return line

        def wrap(self, text):
            self.lines = []
            words = []
            if self.fill:  # SKWM
                for word in text.split():
                    wordlen = len(word)
                    if wordlen <= self.width:  # fixed MRM
                        words.append(word)
                    else:
                        for i in range(0, wordlen, self.width):
                            words.append(word[i:i+self.width])
            else:
                for line in text.split('\n'):
                    for word in line.split():
                        for i in range(0, len(word), self.width):
                            words.append(word[i:i+self.width])
                    words.append('\n')
                if words[-1] == '\n': words.pop() # remove trailing newline

            if words:
                current = words.pop(0)
                for word in words:
                    increment = 1 + len(word)
                    if word == '\n':
                        self.lines.append(self.align(current))
                        current = ''
                    elif len(current) + increment > self.width:
                        self.lines.append(self.align(current))
                        current = word
                    else:
                        if current:
                            current = current + ' ' + word
                        else:
                            current = word
                if current: self.lines.append(self.align(current))

        def getline(self, index):
            if index < len(self.lines):
                return ' '*self.margin + self.lines[index]
            else:
                if self.pad:
                    return ' ' * (self.margin + self.width)
                else:
                    return ''

        def numlines(self):
            return len(self.lines)

    def __init__(self, colspeclist):
        self.columns = []
        for colspec in colspeclist:
            self.columns.append(TextFormatter.Column(**colspec))

    def compose(self, textlist):
        numlines = 0
        textlist = list(textlist)
        if len(textlist) != len(self.columns):
            raise IndexError("Number of text items does not match columns")
        for text, column in zip(textlist, self.columns):
            column.wrap(text)
            numlines = max(numlines, column.numlines())
        complines = [''] * numlines
        for ln in range(numlines):
            for column in self.columns:
                complines[ln] = complines[ln] + column.getline(ln)
        return '\n'.join(complines) + '\n'


def test():
    import textformatter

    formatter = textformatter.TextFormatter(
        (
            {'width': 10},
            {'width': 12, 'margin': 4, 'fill': 0},
            {'width': 20, 'margin': 8, 'alignment': textformatter.RIGHT},
        )
    )

    print(formatter.compose(
            (
                "A rather short paragraph",
                "Here is\na paragraph containing a veryveryverylongwordindeed.",
                "And now for something\non the RIGHT-hand side.",
            )
         )
    )


__all__ = [TextFormatter, LEFT, CENTER, CENTRE, RIGHT]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Thanks, the other solution is quicker to implement though :)

Comment: @seaworthy, _any_ code you don't have to write is quicker to implement :)