# using on other words length for formatted string

Tags: python, string, printing, output

I want to have output like this:

```
      col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
row1    1     1     0     1     1
row2    1     0     0     1     0
row3    1     1     1     1     1
row4    1     0     0     0     0
```

problem is that length of the col1 can change quite a lot so how can I get this done?

I tried to use len(col1), len(col2) and len(col3) and use it when formatting the the stuff inside the rows.

```
x=len(col1)
print "%xd %yd..."
```

and its not working.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685195/line-up-columns-of-numbers-print-output-in-table-format

Comment: You might be interested in [prettytable](http://code.google.com/p/prettytable/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
>>> print("%*d" % (x,33))
```

in Python 2.X, it should be:

```
>>> print "%*d" % (x,33)
```

Comment: This was what I were looking for. thank you.