# Row size in Python (cmd)

Tags: python, text, formatting, tabular

I have text file like this:

```
A fistful of Dolars|Western|100|Sergio Leone|Clint Eastwood|Italia|1964
For a few dolars more|Western|130|Sergio Leone|Clint Eastwood|Italia|1965
The Good, the Bad and the Ugly|Western|179|Sergio Leone|Clint Eastwood|Italia|1966
```

And I try it to format on this way:

```
def movie_list():
    movies = open('movies.txt','r').readlines()
    for i in movies:
        movie = i.strip("\n").split("|")
        for args in (('Name','Genre','Running time', 'Director', 'Starring', 'Country', 'Released'),(movie[0], movie[1], movie[2], movie[3], movie[4], movie[5], movie[6]+"\n")):
            print (('{0:<13} {1:<10} {2:<10} {3:<13} {4:<13} {5:<8} {6:<4}').format(*args))
```

And on few similar ways...

How to set size of row depending of length of string for each line in text file (i.e. movie)

(I did it in paint :D)
The best way is to look like this:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do.  Do you want the title column width to be the width of the longest title from any row?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/3685943/8881141 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/9989441/8881141

Comment: @Piinthesky I tried on this way stackoverflow.com/a/9989441/8881141 but then it's every row resized on size on longest string.

Comment: This one keeps track of the width for each column: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12065663/8881141 The best solution is not always the one with most votes.

Answer (score 0):

Following the methodology outlined in [stackoverflow.com/a/12065663/8881141](http://%20stackoverflow.com/a/12065663/8881141) works nicely:

```
movies = []

with open('movies.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        movies.append(line.strip('\n').split('|'))

f.close()

widths = [max(map(len, col)) for col in zip(*movies)]

for movie in movies:
    print('   '.join([col.ljust(val) for col, val in zip(movie, widths)]))
```

It's worth noting that a monospace font is required to get the desired appearance.